# reloadSections:withRowAnimation: automatically scrolls UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I am using a `UITableview` with dynamic height rows, and in content I have "Read more" type button. On tapping the button, I append data in a row and call `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` for that section.

Everything works as expected, with just one problem - that the tableview automatically scrolls to some other cell after `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`. Can anyone help me to find out why it is happening ?

Comment: how many sections do you have? i think you have to reload rows not section.

Comment: @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani see I am following this https://github.com/2359media/STXDynamicTableView so in my case no. of section = no. of posts.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I had the same issue. Finally found that it's my section's height is not long enough to occupy the screen, so table view has to scroll.